# How to store large multidimensional Array in Redis?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redis

I'm developing a multiplayer game where I'd like to store the game state in Redis.

I have a map as a grid like so:

```
let mapState = {
    gameId: 1214151,
    map: [
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    ]
```

Where each first-dimension is a row of the grid-map and each `[x,y]`-Array, `x` is the type of tile and `y` who owns it.
Now I thought about storing the whole array as a `String` but there might be a better approach?

Maybe as Object?

```
let map = {
    0: [0,0],
    1: [0,0],
    2: [0,0],
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Any advices are highly appreciated!

Comment: I've actually done something incredibly similar -- and with redis too (albiet a couple years ago). You don't actually have to store the entire grid, just the boundaries. And since each player has their own meta-data, they hold their own coordinates. Just some food for thought, since it's not a direct answer to your question

Comment: JSON.stringify(mapState) ?